# How to focus certain component

Tags: codenameone

I have added one container with boxlayout with Y axis and adds multiple buttons and I want to focus to certain position of the container how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Component.requestFocus()`.

Comment: There are around 50 buttons and i try to focus on certain button using following code
     Button button = (Button) container.getComponentAt(25);
            button.requestFocus();
But the button is not focus instead its showing first button ,

Comment: Make sure you call that method when the form is laid out and validated. If you do this before the form is shown layout might never have occurred. You can use a show listener to bind the request focus call if the form isn't visible yet

Comment: thanks it works after adding  addShowListener listener